# Filter a generic list with a dynamic condition string with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using .NET 3.5

I have a List of Company.cs objects.

I want to filder a this list dynamically with LINQ that means the user enters this string in a textbox:

```
(CompanyName = "Google") OR 
(Country = "Czech Republic") or
 (CompanyName = "Microsoft") AND
 (Country = "USA")
```

How can I use this string together with linq and a .Where() clause to filter the existing company objects?

Or is it better at all to use a DataTable and use the Select method?

Comment: That's seemingly a nasty UI design that requires users to input that level of complexity... isn't it?

Comment: Consider revising your UI, using multiple textboxes and/or some dropdowns, and each one for filtering upon a field.

Answer (score -3):

Check out the [Dynamic LINQ library](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation).

Edit:

Sorry, I've misunderstood you.

If you have company and country lists like:

```
var compNames = new[] { "Boo", "Foo" };
var countries = new[] { "Germany", "Bubu" };
```

Then you can filter like this:

```
from c in companies 
where compNames.Contains(c.Name) || countries.Contains(c.Country)
select c
```

Comment: He needs to do a specific Where filter on a type known at compile time, so why would he need Dynamic LINQ ?

Comment: @SirajMansour YES and NO... as I said the condition is a string defined by the user which could be a consultant knowing sql... I want to use LINQ with this dynamic string and Dynamic Linq library looks fine!